# Can't locate an M.2 drive in new machine

Tags: ssd, m.2, nvme

I've just built a new machine with the following (significant) specs:

- MB: Gigabyte Z97X-UD3H-BK
- CPU: Intel i7-4790K
- SSD: Samsung SM951 NVME 256GB M.2

There's no OS as yet.

What I'd like to do is use the Samsung as my primary drive, but I'm unable to find it within BIOS. The MB manual is rather useless in this area. All instructions that close to my issue are for other boards, with different BIOS settings, and I'm beginning to lose hope. Help!

Comment: There are two types of M.2 devices.  One is a PCE-E device the other is a SATA 3 device.  Which one are you using precisely

Comment: @Ramhound SATA3. Sorry for the omission.

Comment: So are you connecting the drive to the  `M.2` connector or the `SATA` port on the motherboard?

Comment: It's a native M.2 connector on the board. Although, if used, it disables SATA ports 4 and 5.

Comment: That is what I thought, I wanted to make sure, are you sure your installing it right? there anyway you can verify the device even works?

Comment: According to someone else who's offered help elsewhere: "you probably won't see the M.2 card in BIOS. My card only shows up during the POST phase". He then goes on to explain how to install the OS. Seems it's just not meant to show up yet...

Comment: I am going to guess the reason it isn't showing up is because the lack of EFI drivers.  There is no point in offering, to boot to a drive, that can't be used to actually boot the system.  If you partition the drive it should be visible in the UEFI shell at that point.  In most cases M.2 devices are are not supported in Legacy/Compatibility mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32465/discussion-between-verism-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 0):

You want to boot from the SSD. That means it must be recognised at some stage between "turn power on" and "OS and drivers are loaded".  This in between stage is usually the firmware on a motherboard. We tend to call it the BIOS in the PC world, though it has different names on other platforms. And even in the PC world the actual BIOS programs has been replaced by EFI firmware or coreboot.

In your specific case you have an EFI firmware (and no BIOS).

Regardless of what is started after power is turned on, it cannot use most devices unless it known how to control it. A sort of build-in driver.

E.g old firmwares did not know about the then new USB. Upu could only use a regular PS2 keyboard until after the OS was loaded. After a few years USB got common and most new PCs shipped with a BIOS which understood the USB protocol.

At the moment we are at the same place with NVME. If your board has no build in support for NVME it cannot boot from it. It sort of makes sense not to show it in the firmware when you cannot do anythign with it.

(Sort of since you cannot change the CPU from the firmware either and they still list it in many cases, even if it is only as information).

Some background on what NVME is might be useful:

Reasonably modern harddrives in consumer desktops often use SAS or SATA. SATA is designed for harddisks and works quite well for it. It takes almost no advantage of the capabilities of an SSD. NVME on the other hand recognises that a lot of potentitial of SSD is wasted by the relative large SATA overhead. By connecting an SSD directly to an PCI-e bus and using a different protocol significant speed advantages can be gained.... But you need a driver which understands the new protocol.

And to make it more confusing: M2 slots ship in several configurations. They **should** al recognise a SATA drive in a M2 slot and treat it as a regular drive from which you can boot. They also should recognise a PCI-e x2 or PCI-x4 drive (both PCI-e v2 and v3) with the NVME protocol. If the firmware has the right drivers it should be able to boot from that.

Sadly M2 is rather new and not all boards are up to spec yet. Some only support SATA. Some only NVME. Some offer the NVME interface but no drivers, **meaning that you cannot boot from the drive but that you can access it after the OS has loaded** (e.g. as a data drive).

Also, recent Intel board ship with rather few PCI-e lanes and boards are trying to work around that. THis often means that a motherboard offers many features, but that you can only use a few of them at the same time. E.g. if you use an M2 SATA drive then many boards disable a regular SATA port. If you use a NVME drive many boards disable 2 or 4 SATA port. (or keep the SATA ports and no not enable the M2 drive).

These things are usually in the motherboard manual and the only solutions are the read it carefully, or to buy Haswell-E or similar solutions with enough PCI-e lanes to enable all features.